# How to print full stack trace in exception?

Tags: c#, exception, stack-trace

For example, in one place...

```
//---------------a
try
{
    // some network call
}
catch(WebException we)
{
    throw new MyCustomException("some message ....", we);
}
```

...and in another place...

```
//--------------b
try
{
    // invoke code above
}
catch(MyCustomException we)
{
    Debug.Writeline(we.stacktrace);   // <----------------
}
```

The stacktrace I print, it only start from a to b,
it doesnt include the inner stacktrace from the WebException.

How can I print all the stacktrace???

Comment: Note that the stacktrace for the originating WebException would not be printed  because you threw a new exception rather than re-throwing the WebException.  Use `throw;` in lieu of `throw new MyCustomException(...)` if you want to preserve (and output) the original exception stack.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

I usually use the `.ToString()` method on exceptions to present the full exception information (including the inner stack trace) in text:

```
catch (MyCustomException ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Sample output:

```
ConsoleApplication1.MyCustomException: some message .... ---> System.Exception: Oh noes!
   at ConsoleApplication1.SomeObject.OtherMethod() in C:\ConsoleApplication1\SomeObject.cs:line 24
   at ConsoleApplication1.SomeObject..ctor() in C:\ConsoleApplication1\SomeObject.cs:line 14
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ConsoleApplication1.SomeObject..ctor() in C:\ConsoleApplication1\SomeObject.cs:line 18
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.DoSomething() in C:\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 23
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 13
```

Comment: Very good. I was looking for a simple way to do it and here it is.  Some little concern is it is not as much explicit as if you use exception.StackTrace object (for example).  I wonder if there is a more explicit way to do the same?

Comment: Be aware that some libraries override the `ToString` method and print custom messages instead of the full information (this is a bad coding practice, so do **not** do that, ever)

Comment: @Pரதீப் I use `ToString` whenever I'm sure it is not overwritten, and use the properties directly otherwise (like [Andrew Hare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4272601/3136474)).

Comment: Silly me for using `exception.StackTrace` and thinking it would work

Answer (score 63):

Use a function like this:

```
    public static string FlattenException(Exception exception)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while (exception != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(exception.Message);
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(exception.StackTrace);

            exception = exception.InnerException;
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
try
{
    // invoke code above
}
catch(MyCustomException we)
{
    Debug.Writeline(FlattenException(we));
}
```

Comment: Or you can use `ToString`?

Comment: I'm using the ToString and think it's fine. I'd go with Andrew's solution if i only want the lowest inner exception (with the actual reason) or similar picking.. works both though :)

Comment: This is more flexible that just ToString, because you can choose what goes into that string. Maybe I'm only interested in the stack traces, not necessarily the messages. Or I want it as a List<string> not a single string.

Comment: What about the inner exceptions?

Comment: @Clark Originally (in .NET Framework 2.0 through 3.5) `Exception.ToString()` did not output details of `InnerException` (or `AggregateException.InnerExceptions`) however I believe since .NET Framework 4.0 (which *post-dates* this answer, as it came out in late 2010 IIRC) *does* include the `InnerException` object-graph in `ToString()`'s output.

Answer (score 24):

**1. Create Method:** If you pass your exception to the following function, it will give you all methods and details which are reasons of the exception.

```
public string GetAllFootprints(Exception x)
{
        var st = new StackTrace(x, true);
        var frames = st.GetFrames();
        var traceString = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var frame in frames)
        {
            if (frame.GetFileLineNumber() < 1)
                continue;

            traceString.Append("File: " + frame.GetFileName());
            traceString.Append(", Method:" + frame.GetMethod().Name);
            traceString.Append(", LineNumber: " + frame.GetFileLineNumber());
            traceString.Append("  -->  ");
        }

        return traceString.ToString();
}
```

**2. Call Method:** You can call the method like this.

```
try
{
    // code part which you want to catch exception on it
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Debug.Writeline(GetAllFootprints(ex));
}
```

**3. Get the Result:**

```
File: c:\MyProject\Program.cs, Method:MyFunction, LineNumber: 29  -->  
File: c:\MyProject\Program.cs, Method:Main, LineNumber: 16  -->
```

Comment: Quite helpful. I've made an [extension method](https://github.com/VeaceslavWD/EasySharp/blob/master/NHelpers/CustomExtensionMethods/ExceptionHelper.cs) based on your example. BTW, in case of a large number of iterations you'd better use `StringBuilder` class.

Comment: Andreys link was dead. This is the current link to his implementation: https://github.com/AndreyWD/EasySharp/blob/master/NHelpers/ExceptionsDealing/Extensions/ExceptionExtensions.cs

Comment: That looks professional Andrey. I put your library in my toolbox. Thanks. @AndreyWD

Answer (score 2):

Recommend to use LINQPad related `nuget` package, then you can use `exceptionInstance.Dump()`.

[image]

### For .NET core:

- Install `LINQPad.Runtime`

### For .NET framework 4 etc.

- Install `LINQPad`

Sample code:

```cs
using System;
using LINQPad;

namespace csharp_Dump_test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                dosome();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Dump();
            }
        }

        private static void dosome()
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Running result:**
[image]

LinqPad nuget package is the most awesome tool for printing exception stack information.
May it be helpful for you.