# typeinitializationexception in listdictionaryinternal

Tags: c#, exception

It happens every time after a file is selected after clicking that button.
servicefactory is what is used to interface with SDK. Also I noticed this started happening after i ran some registry cleaner.
I tried reinstalling drivers but still same error.
[view detail error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIRcr.png)

```
private ServiceFactory serviceFactory;
private PlaybackServices playbackServices = null;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    serviceFactory = ServiceFactory.GetInstance();
}

private void buttonOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Video Files (*.avi;*.mpg;*.mkv;*.ts;*.dvr-ms;*.mp3;*.wtv)|*.avi;*.mpg;*.mkv;*.ts;*.dvr-ms;*.mp3;*.wtv|All files (*.*)|*.*";

    // show dialog
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        playbackServices = serviceFactory.StartPlayback(pictureBox1.Handle, openFileDialog.FileName);
        //player.ShowSubtitles();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The thread 0x1218 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WinTV\WinTVSDK Version 1.1.34005\WinTVSDKTest\bin\Release\WinTVSDKTest.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\DataModel\v4.0_1.1.34005.0__c464d85212b4d2d7\DataModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\WinTVPublic\v4.0_1.1.34005.0__c464d85212b4d2d7\WinTVPublic.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\MultiMediaServices\v4.0_1.1.34005.0__c464d85212b4d2d7\MultiMediaServices.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\NativeMMS\v4.0_1.1.34005.0__c464d85212b4d2d7\NativeMMS.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in DataModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in DataModel.dll
'WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in DataModel.dll
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>WinTVSDKTest.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.TypeInitializationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The type initializer for 'TVServices.Core.SystemSettings' threw an exception.</Message><StackTrace>   at TVServices.Core.SystemSettings.GetInstance()
   at NativeMMS.VideoRenderer.CreateVideoRendererHelper(IGraphBuilder* pGB)
   at NativeMMS.PlaybackVideoFile.PlayFile(IntPtr hwndIntPtr, String filename)
   at TVServices.MultiMedia.ServiceFactory.PlayFile(IntPtr hwnd, String filename)
   at WinTVPublic.ServiceFactory.StartPlayback(IntPtr windowHandle, String filename)
   at WinTVSDKTest.Form1.buttonOpenFile_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\o_abdulrahman\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WinTV\WinTVSDK Version 1.1.34005\WinTVSDKTest\Form1.cs:line 334
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at WinTVSDKTest.Program.Main() in C:\Users\o_abdulrahman\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WinTV\WinTVSDK Version 1.1.34005\WinTVSDKTest\Program.cs:line 17
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'TVServices.Core.SystemSettings' threw an exception. ---&amp;gt; System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at TVServices.Core.SystemSettings..ctor()
   at TVServices.Core.SystemSettings..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at TVServices.Core.SystemSettings.GetInstance()
   at NativeMMS.VideoRenderer.CreateVideoRendererHelper(IGraphBuilder* pGB)
   at NativeMMS.PlaybackVideoFile.PlayFile(IntPtr hwndIntPtr, String filename)
   at TVServices.MultiMedia.ServiceFactory.PlayFile(IntPtr hwnd, String filename)
   at WinTVPublic.ServiceFactory.StartPlayback(IntPtr windowHandle, String filename)
   at WinTVSDKTest.Form1.buttonOpenFile_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\o_abdulrahman\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WinTV\WinTVSDK Version 1.1.34005\WinTVSDKTest\Form1.cs:line 334
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at WinTVSDKTest.Program.Main() in C:\Users\o_abdulrahman\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WinTV\WinTVSDK Version 1.1.34005\WinTVSDKTest\Program.cs:line 17
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Message><StackTrace>   at TVServices.Core.SystemSettings..ctor()
   at TVServices.Core.SystemSettings..cctor()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at TVServices.Core.SystemSettings..ctor()
   at TVServices.Core.SystemSettings..cctor()</ExceptionString></InnerException></Exception></TraceRecord>
```

Comment: Please [print full stack trace of exception](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4272579). It would be more helpful.

Comment: Ok i added full output