# Specified time is not supported in this calendar C# (Hijri Date)

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using C# and I have a strange problem: when I retrieve the date from MySQL and converting it to a string using `ToString()`, it shows an error

> Specified time is not supported in this calendar.

My code:

```
adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adapter.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     table.Rows.Add(row[1].ToString(), row[3].ToString(), row[0].ToString(), row[2].ToString(), row[4].ToString());
}
```

The problem is my code is working fine when I run it on my office PC, but on my laptop it shows this error.

Everything is the same

UPDATE : I'm using Arabic dates (hijri) .

Comment: Do some debugging and try to understand what is different between both environments (office and your laptop). What is the format of the date returned from the database? Do the [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or the [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat(v=vs.110).aspx) match?

Comment: im using arabic dates

Comment: Oh BTW if you could edit your question and paste the full stacktrace of the exception that would be helpful. You need to give us more details.

Comment: My bet is that the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is not the same between your office PC and laptop.

Comment: Are you saying that the error occurs in a call to `.ToString()`. Show us the stack trace. _How_ do you use the Hijri calendar in MySQL, how do you use it in the Operating System (regional settings etc.), and how do you use it in C# (is `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar` a `System.Globalization.HijriCalendar`?)?

Comment: im sorry for being late 
im sorry but i dont know how to get stack trace ? can you help me with that?
@RuiJarimba i copied my code from my office pc so nothing is different with the code .

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen i think it is from .ToString() and the date .
MySQL Date supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'. 
and C# automatically change the datePicker dates to hijri when I changed the system locale and format to (Arabic (Saudi Arabia)).
i didnt change anything in CultureInfo.currentCulture

Comment: @progtariq see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4272629/558486